# Adding an image to an automatically generated dropdown

Tags: javascript, css

I have this script that populates a Semantic UI dropdown with a selection of times based on the choice of another dropdown:

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

  const fromDropdown = $('#fromtime');
  const toDropdown = $('#totime');


  fromDropdown.dropdown();
  toDropdown.dropdown();


  fromDropdown.on('change', function () {
    const selectedTimeFrom = fromDropdown.dropdown('get value');
    const timeToMenu = toDropdown.find('.menu');


    timeToMenu.empty();


    if (selectedTimeFrom) {
      const times = [
        '00:00', '00:30', '01:00', '01:30',
        '02:00', '02:30', '03:00', '03:30',
        '04:00', '04:30', '05:00', '05:30',
        '06:00', '06:30', '07:00', '07:30',
        '08:00', '08:30', 
        '09:00', '09:30', '10:00', '10:30',
        '11:00', '11:30', '12:00', '12:30',
        '13:00', '13:30', '14:00', '14:30',
        '15:00', '15:30', '16:00', '16:30',
        '17:00', '17:30', '18:00', '18:30',
        '19:00', '19:30', '20:00', '20:30',
        '21:00', '21:30', '22:00', '22:30',
        '23:00', '23:30',
        // Add more time intervals as needed
      ];

      for (const time of times) {
        if (time > selectedTimeFrom) {
          if (time < '06:00') {
            timeToMenu.append(`<div class="item" data-value="${time}">${time}</div>`);
          } else {
            timeToMenu.append(`<div class="item" data-value="${time}">${time}</div>`);
          }
        }
      }


      toDropdown.dropdown('set selected', timeToMenu.find('.item').first().data('value'));
    }
  });
  toDropdown.on('change', function () {
    const selectedTimeTo = toDropdown.dropdown('get value');
     
    
  });
});
```

How do I add an image only next to the selected item in the dropdown, just before the displayed time, if the time < 06:00?

Comment: Are you using some sort of dropdown plugin/library? Perhaps I'm mistaken but that doesn't look like anything built into standard JS/jQuery.

Comment: Yes, it is a Semantic UI dropdown